# Accessing values from a restored Tensorflow variable

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, checkpointing

I have a simple recurrent network example, with a `tf.Saver` and `weight`, `bias` and `state` variables being saved.

When the example is run with no options, it will initialise the state vector to contain zeros, but I want to pass a `load_model` option and it to use the last values of the state vector to as a feed for the `session.run` invocation.

All documentation I see insists that one must invoke `session.run` to retrieve stored values from variables, but in this case I want to retrieve the values so that I can initialise the state variable. Do I need to do a separate graph just to retrieve the initialization values?

Example code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import numpy as np

INPUTS = 10
HIDDEN_1 = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 3

def batch_vm2(m, x):
  [input_size, output_size] = m.get_shape().as_list()

  input_shape = tf.shape(x)
  batch_rank = input_shape.get_shape()[0].value - 1
  batch_shape = input_shape[:batch_rank]
  output_shape = tf.concat(0, [batch_shape, [output_size]])

  x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, input_size])
  y = tf.matmul(x, m)

  y = tf.reshape(y, output_shape)

  return y

def get_weight_and_biases():
    with tf.variable_scope(network_scope, reuse = True) as scope:
        weights = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[INPUTS, HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(INPUTS))))
        biases = tf.get_variable('bias', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    return weights, biases

def get_saver():
    with tf.variable_scope('h1') as scope:
        weights = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[INPUTS, HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(INPUTS))))
        biases = tf.get_variable('bias', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        state = tf.get_variable('state', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
        saver = tf.train.Saver([weights, biases, state])
    return saver, scope


def load(sess, saver, checkpoint_dir = './'):

        print("loading a session")
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        else:
            raise Exception("no checkpoint found")
        return

iteration = None

def iterate_state(prev_state_tuple, input):
    with tf.variable_scope(network_scope, reuse = True) as scope:
        weights = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[INPUTS, HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(INPUTS))))
        biases = tf.get_variable('bias', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        state = tf.get_variable('state', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), trainable=False)
        print("input: ",input.get_shape())
        matmuladd = batch_vm2(weights, input) + biases
        matmulpri = tf.Print(matmuladd,[matmuladd, weights], message=" malmul -> %i, weights " % iteration)
        print("prev state: ",prev_state_tuple.get_shape())
        unpacked_state, unpacked_out = tf.split(0,2,prev_state_tuple)
        prev_state = 0.99* unpacked_state
        prev_state = tf.Print(prev_state, [unpacked_state, matmuladd], message=" -> prevstate, matmulpri ")
        state = state.assign( prev_state + 0.01*matmulpri )
        #output = tf.nn.relu(state)
        output = tf.nn.tanh(state)
        state = tf.Print(state, [state], message=" state -> ")
        output = tf.Print(output, [output], message=" output -> ")
        print(" state: ", state.get_shape())
        print(" output: ", output.get_shape())
        concat_result = tf.concat(0,[state, output])
        print (" concat return: ", concat_result.get_shape())
        return concat_result

def data_iter():
    while True:
        idxs = np.random.rand(BATCH_SIZE, INPUTS)
        yield idxs

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_boolean('load_model', False, 'If true, uses model files '
                     'to restore.')


network_scope = None

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, INPUTS))
    iteration = -1
    saver, network_scope = get_saver()
    initial_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(HIDDEN_1))
    initial_out = tf.zeros([HIDDEN_1],
                             name='initial_out')
    concat_tensor = tf.concat(0,[initial_state, initial_out])
    print(" init state: ",initial_state.get_shape())
    print(" init out: ",initial_out.get_shape())
    print(" concat: ",concat_tensor.get_shape())
    scanout = tf.scan(iterate_state, inputs, initializer=concat_tensor, name='state_scan')
    print ("scanout shape: ", scanout.get_shape())
    state, output = tf.split(1,2,scanout, name='split_scan_output')
    print(" end state: ",state.get_shape())
    print(" end out: ",output.get_shape())


    sess = tf.Session()
    # Run the Op to initialize the variables.

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, './tenIrisSave/logsd','graph.pbtxt')
    tf_weight, tf_bias = get_weight_and_biases()
    tf.histogram_summary('weights', tf_weight)
    tf.histogram_summary('bias', tf_bias)
    tf.histogram_summary('state', state)
    tf.histogram_summary('out', output)
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./tenIrisSave/summary',sess.graph_def)
    if FLAGS.load_model:
        load(sess, saver)
        # HOW DO I LOAD restored state values??????
        #st = state[BATCH_SIZE - 1,:]
        #st = sess.run([state], feed_dict={})
        print("LOADED last state vec: ", st)
    else:
        st = np.array([0.0 , 0.0])
    iter_ = data_iter()
    for i in xrange(0, 1):
        print ("iteration: ",i)
        iteration = i
        input_data = iter_.next()
        out,st,so,summary_str = sess.run([output,state,scanout,summary_op], feed_dict={ inputs: input_data, initial_state: st })
        saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=1+i)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
        summary_writer.flush()
        print("input vec: ", input_data)
        print("state vec: ", st)
        st = st[-1]
        print("last state vec: ", st)
        print("output vec: ", out)
        print(" end state (runtime): ",st.shape)
        print(" end out (runtime): ",out.shape)
        print(" end scanout (runtime): ",so.shape)
```

note at lines 124-126 the commented lines for ways that I tried to initialise the feed dictionary values. None of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two placeholders:

- `inputs`
- `initial_state`

From what I understand you want to either (depending on `FLAGS.load_model`):

1. Use an initial state full of zeros

   - this is simple, you just feed a numpy array full of zeros
2. Use the last row on `state`, which is a Tensor in the graph depending on **both** placeholders.

   - you just want to load the value from a previous checkpoint

---

With this analysis done, my first hypothesis is that the error just comes from the fact that you use another tensor named `state` in the line:

```
state, output = tf.split(1,2,scanout, name='split_scan_output')
```

So TensorFlow will try to retrieve this `state`, which depends on both placeholders, instead of retrieving the value of the Variable `state` you want. Just rename the second one and it might work.

You can try:

```
if FLAGS.load_model:
    load(sess, saver)
    with tf.variable_scope('h1', reuse=True)
        state_saved = tf.get_variable('state')
    st = sess.run(state_saved)
```

Comment: 1)  yes this is what is done on the `else` clause at line 129. If you run the script with no `load_model` option you'll see what it is doing. There is only one variable `state`, there is no other variable in the same scope. Notice the line 75: `concat_result = tf.concat(0,[state, output])` in `iterate_state`.

Comment: Can you try the code provided in my last edit? What I meant is that you redefine `state` so when running it with `sess.run(state)`, you get the wrong tensor